# How to Transfer Money Between iTunes Accounts within iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, itunes-store

Is there any way to transfer money in between iTune Accounts within my application, actually I want to develop such app that is capable to do so,
so can anyone help me, or guide with with some proper references?

Comment: No, thankfully that cannot be done.

Comment: and what about purchasing app within my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes is a black hole, it will only take your money, not give it away. Transfering anything through black hole is little bit risky.

If you want to transfer money between two different users (and using app)

- Register users to your service
- Create a mobile site where the payment page is and open this page from within the app - Apple will probably ban your application otherwise as it is really jealous about any non-iTunes payment
- Allow user to choose who will receive the money (friends list?)
- Transfer money using PayPal. For PayPal money receivements, having an email address is enough.

Also check Apple Terms of Service for apps - they probably have some kind of clauses which would limit this type of applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Money out of Itunes,
i believe you could use this trick (**hypotetic**):

You create a fictive In-App purchasement via the Itunes-API for e.g 5€,
I-Tunes will take e.g 1€ and you as the developer will get 4€ transfered to e.g to your PayPal Account minus eg 0,50€ Paypal-Dues.

So now You as the developer will have 3,50 € at your Paypal.
Now you can Transfer this to the Appuser and he will get eg 3,00 € because of the Paypal-Dues.